# problems with the open() function in different file permissions

Tags: c

I am implementing the virtual disk system in C, which includes handling the file system as well. I just want to know, why the `open` function in C returns -1 when I try to open a file with some `group` permission or `others`permissions.

Lets say we have file mode that is 040 (Read permission bit for the group owner of the file):

```
int main(){
    int filedes;
    filedes = open(filename, O_RDWR, 040);
    if(filedes < 0)
        return -1;

    printf("Open success\n");    

}
```

This snippet return without printing **open success**. Where this code with file mode 0644 works perfectly fine

```
int main(){
    int filedes;
    filedes = open(filename, O_RDWR, 0644);
    if(filedes < 0)
        return -1;

    printf("Open success\n");    

}
```

I don't understand why is this happening?

Comment: The mode argument shouldn't do anything here because it only affects newly created files. It is ignored if `O_CREAT` is not specified. What are the permissions of the existing file before you run this code?

Comment: I created the file with same rights (040), with the O_CREAT flag.

Comment: Then you can't open it as O_RDWR because it's read-only. And as I said, you don't need to specify the mode unless you're creating the file.

Comment: So what should I do to read its contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

040 specifically disallows the owner of said file to do anything with it. Even though your group can, you've explicitly defined that your own user can't use it. It may seem weird, but OS only does what you've told it to do.

Comment: But as far as I know, 040 allows the group owner to only "read" the file. Then how can OS deny to open it, if some user can read the file?

Comment: @AhmedDhanani because you've explicitly defined that the owner has access level 0. User specific rules are more important than group rules and group rules are more important than everyone rules. And they override previous ones, not enhance them.

Comment: So that means, this function will again return -1 if I try to open it with read permission for others (04)?

Comment: @AhmedDhanani where do you get that open should return -1? Specs define only that it will return a negative number if there is an issue, not that it will be -1.

Comment: @AhmedDhanani welcome. I understand that this may be counter-intuitive, in the end it is logical to assume that it would only enchants privileges, not potentially reduce them, but it works on overwrite basis, and the relevant value most to the left is the most important one.

Comment: Just one last thing. Will this function only successfully open the file if the file has been created by the user himself?

Comment: @AhmedDhanani it will work as long as the user running the program has access to the file, nothing more and nothing less. If file persmission only allow to be accessed by the owner (600 for example) then only the owner of a file will be able to open it, but if it is more permissive (like 666) then anyone can do it.  You may want ot read up on chmod in spare time http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml